# How can I re-add (or un-remove) a Top Site that I accidentally deleted from the new tab page?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I use the new tab screen as a way to quickly navigate to my frequently visited sites, and I accidentally ×'ed one off.  Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> the moment after it happened didn't undo my miss-click.

How can I add it back?
[image: Top sites illustration]

Comment: Just visit the site lots, it'll forgive you and come back eventually.

Comment: @MichaelFrank It's been a few days so I was hoping there was quick fix

Comment: I haven't had a chance to upgrade to Win 10 yet, what does the `customize` link on the top sites page do?

Comment: So what does the `customize` link do?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Oops brain fart. I meant to show you [what clicking customize does](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jphfy.png).

Comment: Well those are disappointing options... If I get Win 10 in the next couple days I'll be able to take a further look into this. I wonder if it's held in the registry?

Comment: @MichaelFrank Yeah, I'm asking in hopes of a quick hack like that

Comment: @MichaelFrank It eventually came back as you suggested. Heheh. I don't know if you want to answer with that or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually Edge will recognise it as a site you frequent and return it to your top sites list.

It may take a while though, depending on exactly how often you visit the site.

Answer (score 0):

Delete this  EXCLUDE key:
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\TabbedBrowsing\NewTabPage\Exclude`